Branch specific certain subfolders of a project
I have a project with multiples folders (sub-projects) like this
*GreatProject/Trunk/
   /Project1
   /Project2
   /Dependency1
   /Dependency2
   /Dependency3

In my case, I want to create a branch with only Project2, Depencency2 and Depencency3.
Is it possible to create a branch containing needed folders
*GreatProject/Branch/NewFeature/
   /Project2
   /Dependency2
   /Dependency3

We are using TortoiseSVN and I do not know if or how I can do it.
I can create a branch for *GreatProject/ but it is very big and I want to avoid this.

How is the branch being "very big" a problem? Branch creation in Subversion will not duplicate your data. You can easily do it in two steps if you create a branch first and remove all unneeded files afterwards.
